# Saving a blob in JavaScript, while the blob is still being constructed

Tags: javascript, websocket, xmpp, blob

There are several solutions for saving a data blob to a file in a browser environment. I normally use [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js).

In this particular case, though, my data comes in from a websocket stream, and the resulting file might be so large (hundreds of MB) that concatenating it in memory really kills performance.

---

Is it at all possible to open a stream that data can be written to as it comes in?

---

### Edit:

The websocket is an XMPP connection. The file transfer is negotiated via [Stream Initiation (XEP-0095)](http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0095.html) using the [SI File Transfer (XEP-0096)](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0096.html) protocol; the data is then transferred via an [In Band Bytestream (XEP-0047)](http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0047.html).

Basically, the web application gets the data in base64-encoded chunks of 4096 bytes, and I'd like to know if there is any way to let the user save the file before all the data is received.

Comment: Your question could use a lot more context. For instance, by following the link (which I shouldn't have to do), I can see the FileSaver.js seems to be targeted at client-side code running in web browsers. Is that your target environment? And where is the stream coming from?

Comment: If you're receiving the file block by block via  the web socket, can't you just hand each block over to the file system?

Comment: Instead of using websockets you could re-configure your server to send a file.

Comment: If you know how to concatenate them in memory, you can do the same  in files with filesystem api.  Take a look how mega use filesystem to download large file with filesystem api: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994554/download-files-like-mega-co-nz