# Loading message during PHPExcel download

Tags: php, jquery, download, phpexcel

I have a form that, after you select some filters, allows you to download a file via PHPExcel. Well, this file may be large and I want to display a message, an image, or block the download button until the procedure is complete.
I'd rather not have a function with a timeout, but a solution that follows the process to the end.
I tried various guides on the net but I have not found a satisfactory solution.
Can anyone helps me? Thank you!

Comment: Could you add code of the methods you've tried already?

Comment: the few solutions that I found using a timeout method. I wish that the "loader" follow the process until the file is downloaded. I found nothing about it. Thank you!

Comment: A possible solution is downloading files like Mega.co.nz does. take a look at the accepted answer to the following question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994554/download-files-like-mega-co-nz