# Show thumbnail in google maps marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm making a map with pictures using javascript and google maps API 3.

Because I need to show a lot of pictures, so I want to use the thumbnail data stored in the exif headers, hoping that the API doesn't have to process the whole JPEG files.

I did some tests and with syntax below it seems that the API doesn't use the thumbnail in mypicture.jpg

```
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        icon: { url: "myurl/mypicture.jpg",
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(40,30)
        }
    });
```

I tested this by extracting the thumbnails, placing a big red dot over them and inserting them back using jhead. I don't see my red dots appear on the map.

Is there a way to tell the api to just use the thumbnail instead of getting and resizing the full 2-3MB picture?

I also managed to extract the binary thumbnail data myself (using an XMLHttpRequest and ExifParser), so if the api would somehow allow me to pass the binary data for the marker image locally, I'd be happy as well.

Comment: The API doesn't handle the thumbnail data.  You can pass the binary data (as a data url) to the marker.

Comment: No thumbnail handled by the API, OK, I expected that. Passing the binary data as a url means that it must be on a server. But because I just parced it using javascript, the data is local.
So, the binary data is local, the map is local. Do I really need to send the data back to the server for the map to fetch it again?

Comment: You probably don't want to send a 2-3 MB picture to the client in the first place just to display its thumbnail.

Comment: No @geocodezip, I just request the first part of the jpg containing exif data with thumbnail using [XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader('Range', 'bytes=0-65535')](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15561674/2074775), I was hoping that the maps api could be so smart as well.