# Handle XMLHttpRequest response with large data

Tags: javascript, json, rest, google-chrome, firefox

Using Chrome, I setup a `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open(method, url, true);
...
xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      if (isStatusCodeSuccess(xhr.status)) {
        // handle response;
      } else {
        // handle error
      }
    }
};
xhr.addEventListener('progress', event => {
    console.log(event.loaded, event.target.response.length);
});
xhr.send(data);
```

At some point I request some JSON data which total size is around 295MB uncompressed / 5.8 MB compressed. Unfortunately, when the following code is called on success, the response is an empty string.

Using the progress event listener, I can see that the response is correctly handled chunk by chunk, up to a certain point. Here is an excerpt of the console logs it produces:

```
32768 32768
4639135 4639135
7376739 7376739
11525403 11525403
...
261489180 261489180
264684030 264684030
267880247 267880247
271037819 0
274232442 0
277428774 0
...
304018210 0
309230213 0
310445469 0
```

It looks like there is a string/allocation limitation on Chrome but I don't receive any error.

On firefox I receive the following error: `InternalError: allocation size overflow`.

I tried storing the result as it comes but I can't "empty" the Xml Http Request object as attributes are readonly.

**What is the official limitation for variables in browsers?** I could not find an official answer, just some experimental ones  [Javascript string size limit: 256 MB for me - is it the same for all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34957890/javascript-string-size-limit-256-mb-for-me-is-it-the-same-for-all-browsers)

**Is there any way to workaround this issue and handle large POST result?** apart from using WebSocket.

I am thinking of:

- specific content type to stream the data, like the `application/octet-stream`
- specific parameter to handle the data by chunk, like the [range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15561508/xmlhttprequest-206-partial-content) header although the content I'm fetching is not static (it changes over time)
- known algorithm to reduce the length of the JSON response, where I can unzip chunk by chunk the data to avoid hitting the above limitation

Comment: Have you tried requesting data as a `Blob`?

Comment: that's way too much JSON, break it up into smaller pieces or you can't parse it. keep in mind that most js engines only have reach to 0.5-1.0gb, so to store a 256mb string as unicode burns up all to half the ram, then parsing it into an object takes a lot of ram too, as does the resulting object.

Answer (score 4):

You can try using the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), an improved version of the XMLHttpRequest using directly promises. It comes with a feature to **stream the response body** instead of buffering the whole body response as text.

Basically, using the `progress` event, you are called on each chunk but the xhr response keeps accumulating the response as text thus reaching memory limit.

With the `Fetch API`, you can read the received bytes as they arrive:

```
const consume = responseReader => {
    return responseReader.read().then(result => {
        if (result.done) { return; }

        // do something with the current chunk
        const chunk = result.value;

        return consume(responseReader);
    });
}

// Perform the request and consume response stream
fetch(url).then(response => {
    return consume(response.body.getReader());
})
.catch(console.log.bind(console));
```

For more information see this article: [Fetch (or the undeniable limitations of XHR)](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2016/05/24/fetch-and-xhr-limitations/)

Streaming the response body through Fetch API is only supported since Chrome 43, and Edge 14 at the time of writing. Cf [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API#Browser_compatibility).