# Web App - saving to a local file a very large stream of data

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm wondering if there's some proper way (internet protocol, browser API, etc.), for a web app in a modern browser, to get a stream of large data from a Web Server (in my case, nodejs, but the question is focused on client side), and to save it to one big file in the client's file system. The assumption is that the amount of data is too large to be entirely buffered in the App's assigned memory, so I guess somehow the process should append chunks of data from the stream directly to a file.

The data is basically tens of thousands of db records, that should be written to a format such as csv.

Hope I'm making any sense here.

Comment: You mean like a _normal_ file download? Aka, generating the file on the server and then sending that file to the client.

Comment: @George no, the server should stream data from the db and the client should process and build the file

Comment: You will want to use `pipe()`. https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options

Comment: @DiegoZoracKy thanks, but this is an approach for the server side, while I'm asking specifically about the client side

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You asked if there was a *proper* way. No, I'm afraid the technology that does it is badly supported and brand new. However, if you are brave enough to try anyway this is what you have.

**1. Getting a stream of data from Web Server**

If you don't have to support IE then you can use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37402716/handle-xmlhttprequest-response-with-large-data). If you do have to support IE then you could use a websocket to push down little bits at a time.

**2. Writing a stream of data to the disk**

[StreamSaver.js](https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js) Is a project that tries to accomplish this using the [ReadableStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/ReadableStream) API, however it currently only works in Opera and Chrome.