# Read local file with known path in chunks with Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to read file from known path with javascript. At the moment I'm using XMLHttpRequest to get local files but the problem is it loads whole file into memory. This presents a problem when you're trying to read huge files so I want to read files in chunks. [This answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14438187/javascript-filereader-parsing-long-file-in-chunks) deals with it, but it uses FileReader api and File object. Since I already have file path, it seems unnecessary to ask user again to choose file by hand. Is there any way to read file in chunks just by knowing it's path?

Comment: [XMLHttpRequest 206 Partial Content](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15561508)?

Comment: Fetch streams? https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5804334163951616